# How to do sql join to get back rows not in right table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, join

The DB I'm working with has the following 2 tables:

**tblGroup**

- GroupId
- GroupName
- OtherGroupField, etc.

**tblParts**

- PartId
- PartNumber
- GroupId
- Price
- OtherPartField, etc.

In my query I'd like to get the GroupId(s)  which aren't in tblParts for a specified PartNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NOT IN` predicate like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblGroups
WHERE GroupId NOT IN
(
   SELECT GroupId
   FROM tblParts
   WHERE PartNumber = 'Some number'
     AND GroupId IS NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `EXISTS` with a join, rather than `IN` for better performance.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblGroups G
WHERE 1=1
And Not Exists
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM tblParts P
   WHERE 1=1
    And G.GroupId = P.GroupId
    And PartNumber = 'PartNumberGoesHere'
)
```

Comment: I would get rid of the where 1=1 code. It is unecessary and should not be used.

Comment: @HLGEM, this is a trick I use to help with my indentation.  You're free to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
SELECT *
FROM tblGroups G
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblParts P ON P.GroupId=G.GroupId
WHERE P.PartId IS NULL
```

Comment: Just spitting out the query may not be enough you can explain what a left outer join does !

Comment: The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match. so to get missing record or not in, Display record where P.PartId IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188055.aspx)

```
select GroupId from tblGroup
except
select GroupId from tblParts where PartNumber = 22
```

Its a little cleaner syntactically than outer joins even with a single item, but you can also use it to compare whole rows, e.g. looking for all rows of {A,B,C} that exist in table1 but not table2:

```
select A, B, C from table1
except
select A, B, C from table2
```